# Why is GenerationType.IDENTITY not working? Also, column price saying its null when I post in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am doing a SpringBoot Java project simulating a VERY basic ecommerce. I need to do a Post using postman to create a new Invoice to simulate a client buying something. The Post would be like this:

```
{
    "client": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Ramiro",
        "lastname": "Landajo",
        "docnumber": "11111111" 
        },
    "items": [
        {
            "amount": 20,
            "product": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "Control Remoto",
                "code": "123",
                "stock": 50,
                "price": 100.00
            }
        },
        {
            "amount": 2,
            "product": {
                "id": 2,
                "description": "PlayStation 5",
                "code": "567",
                "stock": 2,
                "price": 2000.00
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I have a ClientModel class, a ProductModel class, an InvoiceModel class and inside the invoice model one of the attributes is a list containing InvoiceDetailsModel class which would be the items in the postman request, one for each product. The first problem I am having is that when send the post, the id on the InvoicesDetailsModel doesnt autogenerate and is always null, although I have GenerationType.IDENTITY set up, as you can see here:

```
2023-04-22 20:13:49.832  INFO 14448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.L.D.services.InvoiceService            : Saved Invoice: InvoiceModel(id=3, client=ClientModel(id=1, name=Ramiro, lastname=Landajo, docnumber=11111111), created_at=2023-04-22T20:13:49.788108800, items=[InvoiceDetailsModel(id=null, amount=20, product=ProductModel(id=1, description=Control Remoto, code=123, stock=50, price=100.0)), **InvoiceDetailsModel(id=null**, amount=2, product=ProductModel(id=2, description=PlayStation 5, code=567, stock=2, price=2000.0))], total=6000.0)
2023-04-22 20:13:49.832  INFO 14448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.L.D.services.InvoiceService            : Test: InvoiceDetailsModel(id=null, amount=20, product=ProductModel(id=1, description=Control Remoto, code=123, stock=50, price=100.0))
```

But it still works so maybe thats because of the other error im getting. The other error says the following:

```
2023-04-22 20:13:49.837 ERROR 14448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "PRICE"; SQL statement:
insert into invoices_details (invoice_detail_id, amount, invoice_id, product_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?) [23502-214]
2023-04-22 20:13:49.849 ERROR 14448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRICE"; SQL statement:
insert into invoices_details (invoice_detail_id, amount, invoice_id, product_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?) [23502-214]
```

It says i have an error on line 63 where its where im saving the InvoicesDetailsModel on the DB (which is h2 btw). This is the part of the Invoice service class (that saves the Invoices and the InvoicesDetails, there is no InvoicesDetailsService class).

```
List<InvoiceDetailsModel> listDetails = new ArrayList<>();
for (InvoiceDetailsModel item : newInvoice.getItems()){
    log.info("Prueba: " + item.toString());
    item.setInvoice(newInvoice);
    listDetails.add(item);
    this.invoiceDetailsRepository.save(item);
}
```

I dont understand why it says that price is null when i clearly am sending the price in postman AND it appears in the logs on the IDE. Can anyone PLEASE help me?
Here are the models, schema and invoice service:
InvoiceModel.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InvoiceModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private ClientModel client;
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime created_at; // YYYY-MM-DD ...
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    private List<InvoiceDetailsModel> items;
    @Min(0)
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private double total;

}
```

InvoicesDetailsModel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices_details")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InvoiceDetailsModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "invoice_detail_id")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private InvoiceModel invoice;   //comprobante al que pertenece
    @Min(0)
    private int amount;  //cantidad del producto comprado
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductModel product;

}
```

ProductModel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String code;
    @Min(0)
    private int stock;
    private double price;

}
```

schema

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(75) not null ,
    lastname varchar(75) not null ,
    docnumber varchar(11) unique not null
);

CREATE TABLE products(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description varchar(150),
    code varchar(50) unique not null ,
    stock int,
    price double not null
);

CREATE TABLE invoices(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id int,
    created_at date not null ,
    total double not null,
    constraint fk_client_id foreign key(client_id) references clients(id)
);

CREATE TABLE invoices_details(
    invoice_detail_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id int,
    amount int not null ,
    product_id int,
    price double not null,
    constraint fk_invoice_id foreign key(invoice_id) references invoices(id),
    constraint fk_product_id foreign key(product_id) references products(id)
);

insert into clients(name, lastname, docnumber) values ('Ramiro', 'Landajo', '11111111'), ('Dibu','Martinez', '22222222');

insert into products(description, code, stock, price) values ('Control Remoto', '123', 50, 100), ('PlayStation 5', '567', 2, 2000);

insert into invoices(client_id, created_at, total) values (2, '2023-04-08', 2500), (1, '2023-04-09', 150);

insert into invoices_details(invoice_id, amount, product_id, price) values (1, 1, 2, 2000+500), (2, 1, 1, 100+50);
```

Invoice Service createInvoice method

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class InvoiceService {

    @Autowired
    InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;
    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;
    @Autowired
    InvoiceDetailsRepository invoiceDetailsRepository;
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    public InvoiceModel createInvoice(InvoiceModel newInvoice) throws Exception {
        if (newInvoice == null){        // para chequear que el comprobante no este vacio
            log.info("No se puede crear un comprobante vacio");
            throw new InvoiceEmptyException("No se puede crear un comprobante vacio");
        }

        this.clientService.findClientById(newInvoice.getClient().getId()); //chequear que el cliente existe en la BD

        // chequeamos que haya stock de cada producto a comprar
        for (InvoiceDetailsModel item : newInvoice.getItems()){
            if (item.getProduct().getStock() - item.getAmount() < 0){
                log.info("Stock insuficiente del producto: " + item.getProduct());
                throw new Exception("Stock insuficiente del producto: " + item.getProduct());
            }
        }

        double total = calculateTotal(newInvoice.getItems()); //calculamos el total a abonar

        // seteamos los valores de fecha y total a abonar
        newInvoice.setCreated_at(LocalDateTime.now());
        newInvoice.setTotal(total);

        //guardamos el comprobante y obtenemos el id
        this.invoiceRepository.save(newInvoice);
        log.info("El comprobante guardado: " + newInvoice);

        //creamos una lista para guardar los detalles de cada producto del comprobante en el invoiceDetailsRepository
        List<InvoiceDetailsModel> listDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        for (InvoiceDetailsModel item : newInvoice.getItems()){
            log.info("Prueba: " + item.toString());
            item.setInvoice(newInvoice);            // se le asigna el invoice para que el detalle sepa a que factura pertenece
            listDetails.add(item);
            this.invoiceDetailsRepository.save(item);
        }
        newInvoice.setItems(listDetails);
        log.info("INVOICE COMPLETE : " + newInvoice);

        //actualizamos el stock
        this.productService.updateStock(newInvoice);

        return newInvoice;
    }
```

I tried manually setting the ids in postman and it works but it should be autogenerated, and the price error still shows up. Tried setting Double instead of double and saying @nullable to see if maybe it shows up as null but still saves it on the DB but no good. I know that using a DTO should be the best option and much easier for handling this, but I havent learned how to use them yet.

EDIT: Issues Solved.
I had a column named price in the schema for invoices_details table, and it should not have been there, so deleting it worked perfectly, and the id=null for the invoice_details was happenning because it was not yet saved in the repository, so the id wasn't autogenerated yet, when I fixed the issue the id showed up without a problem. After fixing it I got a Stack Overflow error instead, but i just had to add a @JsonIgnore on the invoice column in the InvoiceDetailsModel so it wouldn't create a cicle.

Comment: Hello, the error is not about price in product table but in inoices_details. You have it defined in DB but not in Java code. Add it to entity and set a value. Or remove from the table if not needed.

Comment: @Mar-Z you are absolutely right, I deleted the price in the schema and the error went away, I got a stackoverflow instead but already solved it. Thanks a bunch!